# How to flip the images on x and y axis with swipe gesture in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Can anybody please help me, how to flip images using swipe gesture in both x and y axis with animation in swift.I found some answers but they were not upto my requirements. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'd want to try to code it yourself first, and if the code not working paste it here and ask what's wrong. The question is too broad right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //MARK: - Image flipping operations performed here.

        func flipImageOnHorizontalAxis(theImage: UIImage,imageView:UIImageView) -> UIImage {

            var orient: UIImageOrientation!
            let imgOrientation = theImage.imageOrientation

            UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {() -> Void in

                switch imgOrientation {

                case .left:
                    orient = .rightMirrored

                case .right:
                    orient = .leftMirrored

                case .up:
                    orient = .upMirrored

                case .down:
                    orient = .downMirrored

                case .upMirrored
                    :
                    orient = .up

                case .downMirrored:
                    orient = .down

                case .leftMirrored:
                    orient = .right

                case .rightMirrored:
                    orient = .left
                }

            }, completion: { _ in })

            let mirroredImage = UIImage(cgImage: theImage.cgImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: orient)
            return mirroredImage
        }

        func flipImageOnVerticalAxis(theImage: UIImage,imageView:UIImageView) -> UIImage {

            var orient: UIImageOrientation!
            let imgOrientation = theImage.imageOrientation

            UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {() -> Void in

                switch imgOrientation {

                case .left:
                    orient = .leftMirrored

                case .right:
                    orient = .rightMirrored

                case .up:
                    orient = .downMirrored

                case .down:
                    orient = .upMirrored

                case .upMirrored:
                    orient = .down

                case .downMirrored:
                    orient = .up

                case .leftMirrored:
                    orient = .left

                case .rightMirrored:
                    orient = .right
                }

            }, completion: { _ in })
            let mirroredImage = UIImage(cgImage: theImage.cgImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: orient)
            //let mirroredImage = UIImage(CGImage: theImage.CGImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: orient)
            return mirroredImage
        }

//MARK: To call the above function this can be done like this:

flipImageOnHorizontalAxis(theImage: imageView.image!, imageView: imageView)

or

flipImageOnVerticalAxis(theImage: imageView.image!, imageView: imageView)
```

Comment: This is without using Gesture but it certainly flips the images Vertical and horizontally.